# Coffeescript getting proper scope from callback method

Tags: jquery, scope, coffeescript, javascript

I've searched for this and can't seem to find an successful answer, I'm using a jQuery ajax call and I can't get the response out to the callback.

Here's my coffeescript code:

```
initialize: (@blog, @posts) ->
    _url = @blog.url
    _simpleName = _url.substr 7, _url.length
    _avatarURL = exports.tumblrURL + _simpleName + 'avatar/128'
    $.ajax
        url: _avatarURL
        dataType: "jsonp"
        jsonp: "jsonp"
        (data, status) => handleData(data)

handleData: (data) =>
    console.log data
    @avatar = data
```

Here's the compiled JS:

```
  Blog.prototype.initialize = function(blog, posts) {
    var _avatarURL, _simpleName, _url,
      _this = this;
    this.blog = blog;
    this.posts = posts;
    _url = this.blog.url;
    _simpleName = _url.substr(7, _url.length);
    _avatarURL = exports.tumblrURL + _simpleName + 'avatar/128';
    return $.ajax({
      url: _avatarURL,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonp: "jsonp"
    }, function(data, status) {
      return handleData(data);
    });
  };

  Blog.prototype.handleData = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return this.avatar = data;
  };
```

I've tried a dozen variations and I can't figure out how to write this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are incorrect, you are passing the callback as the second parameter to `$.ajax`. You should pass it as `success:` in the options, or add it to the Ajax deferred object.

Since handleData looks like it is attached to an object, which is likely `this`, you need to prefix it with `@`.

While your way of passing the URL works, the API now suggests passing the URL as the first param and the options as the second.

```
$.ajax _avatarURL,
  dataType: "jsonp"
  jsonp: "jsonp"
  success: (data, status) => @handleData(data)
```

OR

```
$.ajax _avatarURL,
  dataType: "jsonp"
  jsonp: "jsonp"
.done (data) => @handleData(data)
```

Comment: same here **handleData** never gets called it just returns a method, not the return of **handleData**

Comment: Sorry, what returns a method? initialize? To be clear, at the moment initialize will return a jQuery jqXHR object. http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR. There data is not returned.

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I just needed another cup of coffee. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since `handleData` is in `Blog`'s prototype, not a variable in scope, you probably want this:

```
(data, status) => @handleData(data)
```

Comment: the method never gets executed it just returns the method **handleData** not the actual return of that method.